# org.json.jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject error is obtained for json data GET operation

Tags: java, android, json

My code is successfully retrieving the json data but not displaying in the app due to the error org.json.jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject.
I have tried to use JSONarray but that is triggering chain of other errors.
Please help:

here is my code:

```
public class Main7Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String username;
    public String result;
    EditText contents;
    //public String result;
    public EditText serial1;
    public String serial;
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    TextView myResultTxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);
        Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
        Bundle extraBundle = intentExtras.getExtras();
        username = extraBundle.getString("username");
        serial1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serial);
        serial = serial1.getText().toString();
        contents = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contents);
        Button ret = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ret);

        myResultTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_result);

    }

    public void ret(View v) {

        serial = serial1.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(serial)) {
            serial1.setError("Please Enter the Serial Number");
        } else {
            try {
                Log.w("var23", "api hit in start");
                GetClass apiObj = new GetClass(this);
                apiObj.url = "http://10.43.106.94:8080/SRNSmartLab/rest/service/getNEdata" + serial;
//                apiObj.displayParm = "origin";
                apiObj.execute();
                Log.w("var23", "api hit in executed");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(Main7Activity.this, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }


    /* APi caller */
    private class GetClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final Context context;

        public String url;
        public String displayParm;

        public GetClass(Context c) {
            this.context = c;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
//        progress= new ProgressDialog(this.context);
//        progress.setMessage("Loading");
//        progress.show();
            Log.w("var23", "loading");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Log.w("var23", "doInBackground url : " + this.url);
//            final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
                URL url = new URL( this.url );
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//                String urlParameters = "fizz=buzz";
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.w("var23", "api hit in respomse"+String.valueOf(responseCode));
                final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println("output===============" + br);
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                Log.w("var23", "Result from API: " + responseOutput.toString());
                br.close();

                final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseOutput.toString());
//                final String myUrl =  jObject.getString( this.displayParm );

                String theData = System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString();
               Log.w("var24", "data: " + theData);
                output.append(theData);

                Main7Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // To display any content to ui
                        try {
                            myResultTxt.setText(jObject.getString("url"));
                            contents.setText(jObject.toString());
                            Log.w("var25", jObject.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//                    outputView.setText(output);
//                    progress.dismiss();

                    }
                });

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               Log.w("var26", "error MalformedURLException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.w("var27", "error IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.w("var28", "error JSON exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.w("var23", "end of the line");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

JSON Output :
Output from AndroidStudio: Result from API: [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"} , "LabLocation" : "U02" , "RackLocation" : "EOI-Radio-B01" , "ShelfLocation" : "SH-01" , "VER" : "908762" , "Cluster" : "Radio" , "Name" : "BTS01-Coral-yun-SEW" , "SoftwareVersion" : "LN6.0" , "HardwareType" : "FRGP" , "AssetNo" : "108243" , "SerialNO" : "RY114208612" , "Location" : "zzccg" , "Uname" : "addtvI"}]

Stack Trace :

```
07-15 10:07:28.750 6240-6240/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: api hit in start
07-15 10:07:28.755 6240-6240/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: loading
07-15 10:07:28.756 6240-6240/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: api hit in executed
07-15 10:07:28.756 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: doInBackground url : http://10.43.106.94:8080/SRNSmartLab/rest/service/getNEdataRY114208612
07-15 10:07:28.758 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
07-15 10:07:28.802 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: api hit in respomse200
07-15 10:07:28.804 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs I/System.out: output===============java.io.BufferedReader@506b410
07-15 10:07:28.805 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: Result from API: [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"} , "LabLocation" : "U02" , "RackLocation" : "EOI-Radio-B01" , "ShelfLocation" : "SH-01" , "VER" : "908762" , "Cluster" : "Radio" , "Name" : "BTS01-Coral-yun-SEW" , "SoftwareVersion" : "LN6.0" , "HardwareType" : "FRGP" , "AssetNo" : "108243" , "SerialNO" : "RY114208612" , "Location" : "zzccg" , "Uname" : "addtvI"}]
07-15 10:07:28.807 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var28: error JSON exception
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"_id":{"$oid":"5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"},"LabLocation":"U02","RackLocation":"EOI-Radio-B01","ShelfLocation":"SH-01","VER":"908762","Cluster":"Radio","Name":"BTS01-Coral-yun-SEW","SoftwareVersion":"LN6.0","HardwareType":"FRGP","AssetNo":"108243","SerialNO":"RY114208612","Location":"zzccg","Uname":"addtvI"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at com.example.albbaby.nokialabs.Main7Activity$GetClass.doInBackground(Main7Activity.java:172)
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at com.example.albbaby.nokialabs.Main7Activity$GetClass.doInBackground(Main7Activity.java:127)
07-15 10:07:28.808 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-15 10:07:28.809 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-15 10:07:28.809 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-15 10:07:28.809 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-15 10:07:28.809 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-15 10:07:28.809 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-15 10:07:28.809 6240-6290/com.example.manv.nokialabs W/var23: end of the line
```

Comment: Show the json you get and the complete stacktrace

Comment: Output from AndroidStudio:
Result from API: [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5784818bcb30b4918964b50f"} , "LabLocation" : "U02" , "RackLocation" : "EOI-Radio-B01" , "ShelfLocation" : "SH-01" , "VER" : "908762" , "Cluster" : "Radio" , "Name" : "BTS01-Coral-yun-SEW" , "SoftwareVersion" : "LN6.0" , "HardwareType" : "FRGP" , "AssetNo" : "108243" , "SerialNO" : "RY114208612" , "Location" : "zzccg" , "Uname" : "addtvI"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reponse contains JsonArray but your trying to convert into JsonObject Thats way it showing error.(org.json.jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject.)

**Previous code:**

```
final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseOutput.toString());
```

**Change it as below line:**

```
final JSONArray jArrayObj= new JSONArray (responseOutput.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert JSONArray into JSONObject.

Use this

```
final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseOutput.toString());
```